# remove search button from search form in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css

I need to remove the search button which is normally placed on the right side of the search form and enter default text that appears inside the search form like the one, here on stackoverflow. I just want the text inside the search form to be a little lighter as well. BTW i am using the toolbox wordpress theme but anyways heres the code.

```
<div id="search" class="widget widget_search">
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
</div>
```

I have taken a snapshot of the code in search.php, heres the link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HreJI.png

And heres the css:

```
#searchform label {
display: none;
}

#searchform input#s {
width: 150px;
}

input[type=text],

input#s {
margin: 0 1em 0 0;
width: 60%;
}

textarea {
width: 80%;
}

#search {
float: right;
margin-top: -98px;
margin-right: 22px;
}
```

Comment: cant you just hide it with CSS display:none inside #search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search button can be hidden by simply changing its CSS properties to the following:

```
#search {
    display: none;
}
```

As for placeholder text, you would have to use Javascript or HTML5 in order for that to work, [like detailed at this website](https://web.archive.org/web/20110320034057/http://bulb23.com/html5-forms-placeholder-text).

### EDIT

Based on the form not being quite organized the way the question suggested, just change the CSS above to:

```
#searchsubmit {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: The whole form dissapears when I apply the CSS property display : none to #search. I just want to remove the button. I want it to appear like the one here on stackoverflow. I want only the form to appear

Comment: What is the final HTML of the search? (not the PHP, the output HTML)

Comment: <form id="searchform" action="http://localhost/wordpress/" method="get" role="search">
   <div>
   <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
   <input id="s" type="text" name="s" value="">
   <input id="searchsubmit" type="submit" value="Search">
   </div>
   </form>

Comment: this is a really bad solution, you should make sure that the button never appears by changeing the theme.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren How is this a poor solution? Changing and customizing a new theme would be much more work than adding a CSS equivalent of a one-liner.

Comment: @Nightfirecat, I did choose my words poorly, I am in a bit of a stress and didn't consider that there was a real person at the other end. (internet made me do it). This page was my first google result in a fairly generic search, so I wanted to people to encourage people to look for other solutions. Sorry if you got offended. Now for your question. Generating unwanted code and then adding additional code to hide it will increase load on servers, increase risk of bugs (more code>more bugs), increase the time it takes to introduce a new developer etc.

Comment: This is problems you encounter when a project grows or when you have to take over an other devlopers project. In theese cases it's extremely useful to implement good code-practices, such as seperating markup and design. But if you don't care about that, your solution might save you fifteen minutes or so!

Comment: @KristofferNolgren I'm not sure I agree with this reasoning, since it seems like a *"Oh, there's a pinhole in the wall? Let's get a new wall, then!!"* type of solution. It would be extremely inefficient to replace an entire theme over a small fix to modify some otherwise untouchable HTML code. The load on the servers will be increased minimally, since it's not processed through PHP, it's simply delivered through the already-existing CSS file, and CSS isn't exactly "buggy", since it's a markup language, not a programming language.

Comment: Now, that's not to say that you're not right about needing to keep code clean for other developers to work on the project, but given that this can be noted in the documentation, it shouldn't matter if it's a small fix or an integral feature of the website - it should be commented and noted either way. A simple line reading `/* removes search button on an empty-search, because ... */` would explain the need for the code fully and concisely.

Comment: Well, you don't have to replace the entire theme. If you use the default theme, you can simply clone it, rename it and add a function that overrides the search-widget in functions.php.  It's not about this single solution, it's about a general approach. There is a swedish saying: many creeks add up to a big river. Best practices are created over the year by millions of developers they converge to the best approach. They are rules and rules are ofcorse ment to be broken some times. I encourage you to use whatever approach fit your specific needs the best!